# jquery-ui draggable won't work in chrome on linux - but does work in every other browser I've tried

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, google-chrome, jquery-ui-draggable

I've got a rails app that uses jquery drag and drop.  It definitely works on windows chrome, ie, linux firefox, linux chromium BUT NOT linux chrome!

It seems really odd, because in linux chrome, the draggable image is cloned, snaps to the drop area, but then the drop function isn't called.  The delete function, in the same js does work.  And it all works in all the other browsers I've used!

I've read various stackoverflow questions and answers, but none seem to apply.

Does any one have any ideas?

You can see the application working here - http://rails-drag-drop.herokuapp.com/articles/1/edit

Here's my js

```
$(function() {

  $( make_draggable_and_droppable_and_deletable() );

  function make_draggable_and_droppable_and_deletable() {
    $('.this_is_draggable').draggable({
          helper: 'clone',
          snap: '.this_is_droppable',
          cursor: 'move'
    });
    $('.this_is_droppable').droppable( {
          drop: drop_article
    });
    $(".delete-child_link").click(function() {
          deleteChildArticle(this.id);
    }); 
  }

  function refresh() {
      $("#edit-article-children").load(location.href+" #edit-article-children>*", function (){
          make_draggable_and_droppable_and_deletable();
      });
    }

  function drop_article(event,ui) {
    createChildArticle( this.id, ui.draggable.attr('id') );
  }

  function createChildArticle( parent_id, child_id ) {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:    "/links/",
          data: {link : {
                          parent_id : parent_id,
                          child_id : child_id
                        }
                },
          datatype: "script",
          remote: "true",  
          success: function(){
            refresh();
          }     
    });
  }

  function deleteChildArticle( ChildArticleID ){
    $.ajax({
          type: "DELETE",
          url:  "/links/" + ChildArticleID,
          data: {link : {
                              id : ChildArticleID
                                          }
                },
          datatype: "script",
          remote: "true",  
          success: function(){
            refresh();
          }  
  });
}
//closing document ready tag
});
```

The rest of the code is on github - https://github.com/aldreth/drag-and-drop

Comment: It's working on my Google Chrome under Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Then that's even more bizarre - as it's definitely still not working on mine!  Did it add a new link image to that list when you dropped?

Comment: Yes, it added a link that is when clicked redirect to the article show page.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll keep trying on different browsers....